# How to receive IPv6 multicast datagrams on a specific NIC, specifically how to set up routing tables so I can receive on the NIC I want?

Tags: routes, udp, ipv6, multicast, rhel6

I believe the Linux(RHEL 6) kernel generates routing tables based upon configuration files? Right now I have one linux box that is multihomed(2 NICs - one 10Gb and one 1Gb). I am trying to send multicast datagrams using solely the 10Gb NIC. My multicast code is correct as it works, but I currently only receive multicast datagrams on the 1Gb NIC and send out on the 10Gb NIC(send works because I set IPV6_MULTICAST_IF to go out that NIC). I do not want to have to do this programmatically. My default gateway is set to the 1Gb NIC and DEFROUTE=yes. There is also no multicast route in the routing table.

**Question 1**

Can I change the default gateway and default route to the other NIC and it will do what I want?

**Question 2**

Should there be a multicast route in the routing table(should it be an IPv6 route)? Right now there is none, I assume the kernel looks at multicast destination and realizes it is not in the routing table so it uses the default route?

**Question 3**

If there needs to be a multicast address in the routing table, how do you permanently add it? I use the route command to put it in the table but upon reboot or bringing the NIC up and down, it disappears. Also when adding the multicast route it does not appear to work or route packets the way I want? I still receive on the 1Gb NIC.

I am new to Linux in general and network programming, so bare with my terminology. Please correct me on anything that may be wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you describe your testing scenario more detail. Every NIC should have dedault multicast group address. So there is no need to set it manually

Comment: *"My multicast code is correct as it works"* - can you give a rundown of your system calls, especially the `setsockopt` ones.

Comment: The issue was seemingly resolved by editing the local routing tables of the Linux kernel. There was a forwarding path that was overriding all other routes which caused my application to send and receive on a specific NIC.